# How to range items in for loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to apply a for loop on a non-specified range of rows in a tibble.

I have to modify the following code that applies a for loop on a specific number of rows in a tibble:

```
for(times in unique(dat$wname)[1:111]){...}
```

In this tibble the range from 1:111 corresponds to a specific file, in fact, the value of the column "File" repeat 111 times. However, in my data, I do not know how many times the same file repeat. For example, I can have a file that repeats for 80 rows and another for 85. How do I tell the loop to look only in the range in which the rows in the column file have the same name?

I need something to say:

```
for(times in unique(dat$wname)["for each row in the column File with the same name"]){...}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. See [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) for tips on how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of rows using nrow, or ncol if you want to use columns,in your dat variable or lenght in `unique(dat$wname)` and do something like this:

```
rows= nrow(dat) # OR
rows=length(unique(dat$wname))

for(times in unique(dat$wname)[1:rows]){...}
```

But a reproducible example would make things a lot easier to understand/answer

Comment: @G.Frenandes,  I want to test the stationary of time series data , build ARIMA models, predicting, every 30 rows of the time series, how can I go about it? I have multiple time series data in a long format under the same variable and a single time series has 30 years of data, I want to replicate the 30 years time series in to 4, i.e 4*30= 120 observations. Thank you very much for your assistance!